# How to order by closest date to today using Angular2 pipe

Tags: javascript, html, angular, sorting, angular2-pipe

Say I have an `Event` collection:

```
export class Event {
  startingTime: Date
}
```

And I want to display them ordered starting from the closest to TODAY, what would that `OrderByUpcomingToLatestPipe` look like?

`<event-element *ngFor="let event of events | orderByUpcomingToLatest"></event-element>`

### Edit:

I want the array to be arranged in descending order when the date closest to today is the first and the date that is the farthest from today is the last (dates that have already passed will be after the far ordered the same way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's the working pipe

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: "upcomingToLatest"
})
export class UpcomingToLatestPipe implements PipeTransform{
  transform(array: any, fieldName: any): any {
    if (array) {
      let now: Date = new Date();

      array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
        let date1: Date = new Date(a.object[fieldName]);
        let date2: Date = new Date(b.object[fieldName]);

        // If the first date passed
        if(date1 < now){
          // If the second date passed
          if(date2 < now){
            return 0
          } else {
            return 1
          }
        } else {
          // If the second date passed
          if(date2 < now) {
            return -1
          } else if(date1 < date2) {
            return -1
          } else if(date1 > date2) {
            return 1
          } else {
            return 0;
          }
        }
      });
    }

    return array;
  }
}
```

A quick explanation for that `if` tree:

1. If the first date is in the past

   1.1 If the second date is in the past - the order of them does not matter

   1.2 Else, meaning the second is in the future, bring second date higher in the order
2. Else, meaning the first date is in the future

   2.1 If the second date is in the past, bring first date higher in the order

   2.2 Else if the first date is before the second date, meaning first date is closer to `now` than the second date, bring first date higher in the order

   2.3 Else, meaning the second date is closer to `now` than the first date, bring the second date higher in the order

Answer (score 5):

Don't use pipes for ordering. Snippet from the [Pipes documentation](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe):

> Appendix: No FilterPipe or OrderByPipe
>
> Angular doesn't provide pipes for filtering or sorting lists.
>   Developers familiar with AngularJS know these as filter and orderBy.
>   There are no equivalents in Angular.
>
> This isn't an oversight. Angular doesn't offer such pipes because they
>   perform poorly and prevent aggressive minification. Both filter and
>   orderBy require parameters that reference object properties. Earlier
>   in this page, you learned that such pipes must be impure and that
>   Angular calls impure pipes in almost every change-detection cycle.

You should sort your events in your service or component, possibly using something like [Lodash](https://lodash.com/):

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';

this.sortedEvents = _.sortBy(this.events, e => p.startingTime);
```

And then in your template:

```
<event-element *ngFor="let event of sortedEvents"></event-element>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this custom pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core"

@Pipe({
    name: 'OrderByUpcomingToLatestPipe '
})
export class OrderByUpcomingToLatestPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
        let newVal = value.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
            let date1 = new Date(a.date);
            let date2 = new Date(b.date);

            if (date1 > date2) {
                return 1;
            } else if (date1 < date2) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        });

        return newVal;
    }

}
```

<kbd>[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zIwFZglcEGCm76DThHra?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Im pretty sure there's no comparison with TODAY in that, only between two instances of dates, hence it wont be sorted by upcoming to latest, am i wrong? there is no `let today = new Date()` involved. I've updated the question with a suggestion to the already passed dates

Comment: but i guess if you passed proper format of date than whether it will be today or tommorow does't matter, it will comapre automatically, isn't it ?

Comment: This will arrange the order in descending order by date, I want the array to be arranged in descending order when the date closest to today is the first and the date that is the farthest from today is the last (dates that have already passed will be after the far ordered the same way)

Comment: Any chances you'll be able to help me achieve such behavior? :')

Comment: i'll try to achieve, once done i'll leave comment here.

Comment: Check my answer, let me know what you think ;)